# How does delete operation work with Rest in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data, crud, spring-data-rest, http-delete

Currently we have exposed our methods like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app/person")
public class PersonResource {

    @Timed
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Person: {}", id);
        personRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

The operations of this method, in terms of input and output, are very clear to the user developer.

This article http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/ shows how to expose JPARepositories directly obviating the need of a service layer.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="people", path="people")
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {

}
```

It is not obvious to me how I can make a "delete operation" available with PathVariable Long id.

There is an excellent article on this topic. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/wiki/Configuring-the-REST-URL-path 
But it actually shows how to supress export of a delete operation.

Answer (score 4):

As documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.item-resource), Spring Data REST will expose item resources for the repository you declare. Thus, all you need to do is discover the URI of the resource to delete and issue a `DELETE` request to it.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance Oliver, how do you mean "you need to do is discover the URI of the resource to delete" ?

Comment: He means you need to get the URL on the server for that object so you can delete it like this by sending a DELETE to it: DELETE http://localhost/app/persons/user721025 where user721025 is your user id / long.

Comment: Is it possible to send a message to client when an entity is deleted using RepositoryEventHandler?